# XML-element with content #PCDATA or list of elements

Tags: xml, pcdata, dtd

I like to define a DTD with an element like following:

```
<result>
<name/><resultType/>[more elements...]
</result>
OR it could be:
<result>Some text</result>
```

My element definition looks like that:

```
<!ELEMENT result ((name,resultType,...,pages)|#PCDATA)>
```

But Visual Studio says that this isn't valid.

Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 2):

The `#PCDATA` has to be one of the elements listed in the parenthesis and delimited by `|`. Try:

```
<!ELEMENT rootelement (#PCDATA|childel1|childel)*>
```